# dig a SRV record to host:port format directly?

Tags: dns, dig

`dig some.domain SRV +short` gives me an output like:

```
1 1 1234 real.location.of.some.host.
```

Is there a way of getting the output directly as `real.location.of.some.host:1234`, without a couple of `cut`s or similar?

(I have seen mysql for example supports a `tcp+srv` scheme, I don't know how standard that is, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be an option in my case, I need an A record domain or an IP.)

Comment: This can be done with very sample `awk` program. Are you OK to test it?

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear - I'd call that 'similar' to 'a couple of `cut`s'. I was hoping for some `dig` incantation that was eluding me - but I also held a mistaken unstated assumption that `dig`/`host` resolve a single record according to the priority and weight of the possibly multiple results. I wrote a little python script to achieve both things, such that I can just write `tcp://$(choose-srv _something._tcp.whatever)`.